# How would apportionment be handled if a state were split in two or more states as a state?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives

I saw a proposal online saying to split California into two states: North California and South California. The demarcation between the two Californias would be the separation between present day NorCal and SoCal. The reason provided is to counter the Senate's Republican bias. The two states would be electorally very similar with South California being more populated with a smaller land area.

This raises an interesting question. If California or any other state were split into two or more states would apportionment be handled federally?

Comment: As far as I can determine that has zero chance of happening and people have been talking about it for a long time.

Comment: Apportionment of representatives, taxes, land, or something else?

Comment: @StuartF: given the house-of-reps tag and no other, I'm guessing it's only asking about representatives.

Comment: Theoretically it wouldn't have much of any effect on the House since the combined population would be the same.  Where it *would* have significant effect would be in the Senate, adding 2 most-likely-Democratic senators.  Similar proposals have been brought up to split the state of Texas.  (Depending on how it's split, this might also favor the Democrats, as south TX is much bluer than the rest of the state.)  The fact that any such split only favors one party means it's highly unlikely to get bipartisan approval in either case.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Now splitting _Alaska_ would _double _ the number of their representatives in the senate (house?).

Answer (score 9):

Q: *If California or any other state were split into two or more states[, how] would apportionment be handled federally?*

Apportionment must be done according to the official decennial census ([Article I, Section 2, Clause 3](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artI-S2-C3-1/ALDE_00001034/)). At the time of Congressional approval of the split, Congress will state the number of representatives to which each state is entitled. This may increase the total number of representatives in the House by one or more until the next official census. No states will lose representatives until the apportionment following the next census.

Comment: This is the nice, simple answer.  In order to split a state, Congress needs to pass a law, and that law will indicate how to handle the division.

Comment: As an example of this, [the law admitting West Virginia to the Union](https://catalog.archives.gov/id/299813) granted it three representatives until the time of the next general census.

Answer (score 2):

So the House of Representatives are all elected every two years on even numbered years.  Typically if there are vacancies in the House, they are dealt with by proximity to the next election.  If the next election is soon (usually under a year), the seat will likely be vacant until elections are held.  If it's not soon, a special election would be held for candidates to fill the remaining term.  In either case, the current representatives will likely hold onto their current districts and just switch their state to the ones their congressional district presently represents.  It might even be that the border is drawn based on present congressional district lines to avoid a district being split between two states.

As for the Senate, things would be different.  Senators serve six year terms and are voted in one of three staggered elections held every two years (Class 1 Senators, Class 2, and Class 3).  The net affect is that one third of the senate is elected in every election and Senators voted into office in a Presidential Election Year will be up for re-election during a Mid-term election and vice versa.   The upcoming 2022 mid-term elections will see an election of all Class 3 scheduled Senators, or those who were elected in 2016.

Classes are assigned to a new state when they enter the union and are done so at random but in a way that best balances the classes.  Likely optimal solution is that each of the California's will keep one of the existing Senators for that state, and be given a single new Senator with a new class, but this might not work if both Senators live in the North or South.

It should be pointed out that any vacancy in the Senate will be filled by the Governor until the next election day, where a special election will be held to fill the seat until that seat is up for re-election with the rest of its class.  That means that if California (which has a Class 1 and Class 3 senator) has a vacancy following the election of its class 3 Senator (who ever wins the Nov 22 elections) the sitting governor will name the new Senator who will serve until the 24 elections where a voted Senator will be elected in a special election (Along with the class 1 Senator, who is scheduled for a 2024 election) and will then the new Class 3 senator will serve the remaining class 3 term until 2028.

It should be pointed out that all states officially enter into the Union on July 4th of the year of their entry and by tradition, the new flag (with the new state(s) star added) is first raised at Fort McHenry in Baltimore, Maryland, which was the site of the battle described in "The Star Spangled Banner". (Presumably all other East Coast federal instillations will delay their otherwise timely Flag Raising to wait for Ft. McHenry's.).

It should be noted that this would not be the first time a state split into two states as it has happened twice in U.S. History (Massachusetts split into its present day territory and Maine in 1820 and Virginia Split into its present day territory and West Virginia in 1861-63 (it's complicated.  Suffice it to say, West Virginia was the part of Virginia that was pro-Union and seceded from Virginia when it seceded from the Union.  For this reason, it's probably better to look at Mass/Maine and how it handled the situation).  If the States formed a North CA. and South CA., it would be the first time a state split into two and had no clear successor state.

Finally, look up "The State of Jefferson" which was an effort to make much of Northern California (and a small bit of Southern Organ that borders California) into a new State of Jefferson, which gained the most traction.  It was slated for Congressional hearings in late 1941, but the death of the Gilbert Gable, a major political leader in the movement from Oregon on December 2nd dealt a critical blow to the effort, but the final death knell for the movement was the following Sunday, when a little place in the middle of the Pacific Ocean called Pearl Harbor was suddenly thrust into the national spotlight and the scheduled Dec 8th congressional committee hearing on The State of Jefferson was postponed so then President Franklin Delano Roosevelt could make a case for war on Japan.  The movement lost interest as the supporters committed to the war effort.

The people of Jefferson wanted the seperation from their two parent states because they felt (and to this day still feel) that their state governments did not have their political interests in heart.  They consisted of the mostly rural counties in both states and were consistently outvoted by more Urban population centers on state politics.  Had Jefferson been a state in 2016, Donald Trump would have won 24 of the 28 counties in the state.  It likely wouldn't help solve any "Republican Edge" in the Senate today.  Ironically the best way to break California up would be to revive Jefferson and have it and Puerto Rico admitted into the Union at the same time to offset any unbalancing of Senate Power (Admitting States with opposite political leanings at the same time is a long standing tradition in the U.S. and while the worst of this were adding pro-slavery and pro-abolition states prior to the Civil War so the balance of power never dipped to favor one over the other, Alaska and Hawaii were both added in 1950 so that neither would unbalance the senate in favor of one party.).

Comment: *If the next election is soon (usually under a year), the seat will likely be vacant until elections are held*  Of course, Texas just [held a special election for TX-34](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Texas%27s_34th_congressional_district_special_election) with just over 4 months until the next general election...

Comment: "It might even be that the border is drawn based on present congressional district lines to avoid a district being split between two states": [not a chance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California's_congressional_districts).  "It should be pointed out that all states officially enter into the Union on July 4th of the year of their entry": that is [incorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_date_of_admission_to_the_Union).  The flag doesn't change until independence day, but states may be admitted at any time.

Comment: "It should be pointed out that all states officially enter into the Union on July 4th of the year of their entry". *None* of the states have entered the Union on July 4th of any year. [Idaho was the closest on July 3, 1890](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idaho).

Answer (score 1):

There have been two cases in US history where a new state was created by subdividing an existing state.  In both cases, House apportionment was handled in an *ad hoc* manner until an intervening regular decennial reapportionment.

### 1820: Maine (from Massachusetts)

The District of Maine had long been physically separated (by New Hampshire) from the rest of Massachusetts, and [several previous attempts at secession](http://bicentennial.mainememory.net/page/4614/display.html) had been made.  The separationist movement gained steam after the War of 1812, as Maine residents blamed the Boston government for failing to defend Maine from British invasion.  But it was the Missouri Compromise that finally gave Maine its opportunity for statehood, in order to balance out Missouri's petition for admission as a slave state.

[The Act admitting Maine as a state](https://digitalmaine.com/act_of_separation/5/) declared that the new state would be “admitted into the Union on an equal footing with the original States, in all respects whatever.”  This implied the right to representation in the House of Representatives, but did not directly state how many seats.

[In 1820](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1820_United_States_census#State_rankings), Maine had a population of 298 335, compared to 523 287 for what was left of Massachusetts.  So in theory, Maine should have inherited 36.3% of Massachusetts House delegation, or 7 of its then 20 seats.  But in fact, Maine was temporarily granted [only one House seat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maine%27s_at-large_congressional_district) for the remainder of the 16th Congress.  This was increased to the proper 7 seats for the 17th Congress, after the 1820 Census counts were finalized.

### 1863: West Virginia (from Virginia)

This was a special case, as the Civil War was ongoing, and West Virginians rebelled against the Southern rebellion to rejoin the Union.

Unlike with Maine, [the Act admitting WV as a state](https://catalog.archives.gov/id/299813) specifically stated:

> until the next general census [West Virginia] shall be entitled to three members of the House of Representatives in the United States.

Before the Civil War, the still-united state of Virginia had 13 seats in the House.  After the 1870 census and reapportionment, WV had 3 seats and VA had 9.  (This was an overall decrease of 1 seat.  I guess a disproportionate number of Virginians either died or moved out of state during the war.)

Comment: The 1860 census reported 1,596,318 free people and 490,865 enslaved people in Virginia, which would result in a population for apportionment of 1,890,837.  In 1870, they counted 1,596,318 in Virginia and 490,865 in West Virginia for a total population of 1,667,177 in the former territory of Virginia.  This is a reduction of just over 20% from the former real population of 2,087,183.